# Python: storing return value of a function

Tags: python, function

I want to store the return value of a function in a variable, but every time i use the variable it seems the function ic called again.

Is there any way to only store the result and not executing the function every time ?

```
def get_password(crypto=False):
    pprompt = lambda: (getpass.getpass(), getpass.getpass('Retype password: '))
    p1, p2 = pprompt()
    while p1 != p2:
        print('Passwords do not match. Try again')
        p1, p2 = pprompt()
    if crypto == True:
        p1 = crypt.crypt(p1)
    return p1

passwd = get_password()
```

Using password make a `get_password` call everytime.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case.  Please show how you're "using" `password`.

Comment: How do you know that the function is being called every time you use `passwd`? Also, it should store the value, and not the function. Please show how you are calling the function.

Comment: works for me .... i can see passwd as a string (as expected)

Comment: It's all my bad. I passed the result to mysqladmin, who prompt me with Enter Password (same as getpass() )
I will copy one hundred times : "do not work when yu're tired, it makes you stupid." Sorry all to bother you.